# Export Chrome Net-Internals Events

Tags: google-chrome, tcpip

Are there any options for exporting data captured within Chrome's net-internals tool (chrome://net-internals/)?

The only data that I care about are get requests for JavaScript files from a specific domain. I only care to have the destination URL of each request.

I would prefer to avoid using an external tool for this (i.e. BurpSuite).

Thanks!

[Edit] Also, copy and paste can work, but is a bit inefficient if trying to handle large numbers of items multiple times.